# how to autofill column values in excel according to column A value

Tags: excel, autocomplete

Please excuse the newbie question, I am very unfamiliar with Excel.
Is there a way for me to input a number value in a cell in column A, and then have columns B-D autofill, according to what the number value in column A is?

If it helps to explain, I service many locations for a retail company. What I'm trying to do is be able to fill in a store number in column A, then have column B-D autofill with the location of store, description of service (2-3 words), and frequency of service.

I have almost 100 stores so it would be a huge time saver if I could just input the number into column A and have the rest of the information fill in automatically. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new sheet named **Reference**, with four columns: Column A: **Store Number**, Column B: **Location**, Column C: **Service**, Column D: **Frequency**.

Fill out the data in those columns for all 100 stores.

In your other sheet, columns A - B are the same columns.  For **Store Number**, Click in cell A2, Go to 'Data', then 'Data Validation', make it only allow data from a list, set the 'Source' to:

```
=Reference!$A$2:$A$101
```

Type the following formula in cell B2 for  **Location**:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Reference!$A$2:$D$101,2, FALSE)
```

Then just modify that formula for the other cells.  (Obviously, if your sheet has this not in cell A2, you'll need to make adjustments, but what you need is here.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use =CellReferenceNumber like on D1 you can use =A1 it will auto fill D1 cell with the data present in A1. You can use references as many as you want.